# Is it possible to make texnegar work with arabic poems in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: arabic, arabluatex

I stumbled upon texnegar for resolving kashida issues, and wonder if it is possible to use it to write poems in Arabic either using ArabLuaTeX or any other solutions such as bidipoem.
Also, I don't seem to be able to make the kashida work in any case, following the example given in the documentation.
Here is a sample:

```
    \documentclass[A4paper,11pt]{book}
    \usepackage[Kashida=glyph,kashidastretch=0.14 em plus 0.5 em,hboxrecursion=On,vboxrecursion=On,color=red,ligatures=default]{texnegar}
    \usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}
    \babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
    \babelfont{rm}[Language=Default,Scale=1.5]{Scheherazade}
    \babelfont{sf}[Language=Default]{Scheherazade}
    \babelfont[french]{rm}{Junicode}
    \babeltags{ar = arabic}
    \babeltags{fr = french}
    \usepackage{multicol} 
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{bidipoem}
    \usepackage{arabluatex}    


      \begin{document}
     %Source: https://blogs.harvard.edu/sulaymanibnqiddees/tag/arabic-sufi-poetry/
        
        
        عــليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه   ألا يا رسول الله إنى مغرم عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه   ألا يـا رسول الله إنى مغرم عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه    ألا يا رسول الله إنى مغرم
        
\begin{multicols}{3}
        عــليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه   ألا يا رسول الله إنى مغرم عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه   ألا يـا رسول الله إنى مغرم عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه    ألا يا رسول الله إنى مغرم عــليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه   ألا يـا رسول الله إنى مغرم عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه   ألا يـا رسول الله إنى مغرم عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه    ألا يا رسول الله إنى مغرم
\end{multicols}
        
       
        \begin{traditionalpoem*}
        علـــــيك صلاة الله ثم سلامه    &   ألا يــا رسول الله إنى مغرم
        صَبَبتُ دُمُوعاً يَشهَدُ الحُزنُ أَنَّها   &  أَتَت مِن فُؤَادٍ بالغَرَامِ مُتَيَّمُ
        وَلَيسَ لَهُ مِن ذَا التَّتَيُّمِ مُشرِحٌ      &  سِوَى أن يَرَى مَعشُوقَهُ فَيُسَلِّمُ
        يَقُولُ لِى المَعشُوقُ لاَ تَخشَ بَعدَ ذَا  & حِجاباً وَلاَ طَرداً فَعَهدِى مُتَمَّمُ
        مَتَى ما أردَتَ القُربَ مِنّىِ فَنادِنِى   &  أَلاَ يا رَسُولَ اللهِ إِنِّىَ مُغرَمُ
        أُجُيبُكَ مِن بُعدٍ وَإِنِّى جَلِيسُ مَن    &  بِحُبِّىَ مَشغولٌ بِذِكرى مُتَرجِمُ
        حَلَفتُ يَمِيناً إِنَّ قَلباً يُحِبُّكُم    &    عَلَيهِ عَذابُ النَّارِ قَطعاً مُحرَّمُ
        فَكَيفَ بمَن قَد شامَكُم كُلَّ ساعَةٍ &   فَهذَا يَقِيناً في الجِنانِ يُنَعَّمُ
        سَلاَمٌ عَلَيكُم وَالسَّلاَمُ يُنِيلُنِى     &  كَمالَ شُهُودِ لِلجَمالِ وَيُلهِمُ
        لِسانِى تَحِيَّاتٍ تَلِيقُ بِقَدرِكُم      &   أُكُرِّرُها في حَيَّكُم وَأُهمهِم
        سَلاَمٌ علَى رَأسِ الرَّسُولِ مُحَمَّدٍ   &  لَرَأسٌ جَلِيلٌ بالجَلاَلِ مُعَمَّمُ
        سَلاَمٌ علَى وَجهِ النَّبِىِّ مُحَمَّدٍ      &  فَيا نِعمَ وَجهٌ بالضِّياءِ مُلَثَّمُ
        سَلاَمٌ عَلى طَرفِ النَّبِىِّ مُحَمَّدٍ    &  لَطَرفٌ كَحِيلٌ أَدعجٌ وَمُعَلَّمُ
        سَلاَمٌ عَلى أنفِ النَّبِىِّ مُحَمَّدٍ    &   لأَنفٌ عَدِيلٌ أنوَرٌ وَمُقَوَّمُ
        سَلامٌ علَى خَدّ الحَبيبِ مُحَمَّدٍ   &   لَخَدٌ مُنِيرٌ أسهَلٌ وَمُشَمَّمُ
        سَلاَمٌ علَى فَمِّ النَّبِىِّ مُحَمَّدٍ    &    لَفَمٌّ بِهِ دُرٌّ نَفِيسٌ مُنَظَّمُ
        بِغَيرِ كَلاَمِ اللهِ وَالذِّكرِ وَالنّدَا     &   لِحَضرَةِ مَولاَهُ فَلاَ يَتَكَلمُ
        سَلامٌ علي عُنق النَّبِىِّ مُحَمَّدٍ     &   لَعُنقٌ سَطِيعٌ نَيِّرٌ وَمُبَرَّمُ
        سَلاَمٌ على صَدرِ الحَبِيبِ مُحَمَّدٍ   &   لَصَدرٌ وَسِيعٌ بالعُلُومِ مُطَمطَمُ
        سَلاَمٌ على قَلبِ الحَبيبِ مُحَمَّدٍ    &    لَقلبٌ بِنُورِ اللهِ دَوماً مُقَيَّمُ
        يُشَاهِدُ رَبَّ العَرشِ في كُلِّ لَحظَةٍ   &  فإن نامَتِ العَينانِ ما نامَ فاعلَمُوا
        سَلاَمٌ على كَفِّ النبي مُحَمَّدٍ    &     لَكَفٌ رَحيبٌ كَم يَجُودُ وَيُكرِمُ
        بهِ كَم فَقِيرٍ صَارَ مِن بَعدِ فَقرِهِ    &   غَنِيًّا وَكَم طاغٍ بهِ مُتَضَيِّمُ
        سَلاَمٌ على قَدَمٍِ الحَبيبِ مُحَمَّدٍ   &     بهِ دَاسَ حُجبَ العِزِّ ذَاكَ المُقَدِّمُ
        بهِ قامَ في المِحرَابِ لِلهِ قانِتاً    &      يُناجى لِرَبِّ العَرشِ وَالنَّاسُ نُوَّمُ
        فَما زَالَ هذَا دَأبُهُ كُلَّ لَيلَةٍ       &     إِلى أَن بهِ بانَ الوَنا وَالتَّوَرُّمُ
        سَلاَمٌ على ذَاتِ النبي مُحَمَّدٍ     &    فَيا حُسنَها فِيها الجَمالُ مُتَمَّمُ
        سَلاَمٌ عَلى كُلِّ النبي مُحَمَّدٍ   &       نبي عَظِيمٌ بالجَلالِ مُعَظَّمُ
        نَبِىٌ لِمَولاَهُ العَلِّى عِنايَةٌ          &     بِهِ تَبدُو إِذ ما الخَلقُ في الحَشرِ يُفحَمُ
        عَلَيهِ لِوَاءُ الحَمدِ يُنصَبُ رِفعَةً    &    وَمِن تَحتِهِ الانباءُ وَالرُّسلُ يُزحَمُ
        بِهِ كُلُّ عاص في القِيامةِ لاَئِذٌ     &   وَكُلُّ مُحِبٍّ فائِزٌ وَمُكلَّمُ
        بِهِ يَرتَجِى المَجذُوبُ يَنجُو بِصَحبهِ  &  بِغَيرِ امتِحانٍ يا شَفِيعُ وَيَسلَمُ
        عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه     &     يَعُمَّانِ كلَّ الآلِ ها نحن نختمُ
        
        \end{traditionalpoem*}
        
        \begin{arabverse}
        \bayt{علــيك صلاة الله ثم سلامه}{ألا يــا رسول الله إنى مغرم} \\
        \bayt{صَبَبتُ دُمُوعاً يَشهَدُ الحُزنُ أَنَّه}{أَتَت مِن فُؤَادٍ بالغَرَامِ مُتَيَّمُ} \\
        \bayt{وَلَيسَ لَهُ مِن ذَا التَّتَيُّمِ مُشرِحٌ }{سِوَى أن يَرَى مَعشُوقَهُ فَيُسَلِّمُ} \\
        \bayt{يَقُولُ لِى المَعشُوقُ لاَ تَخشَ بَعدَ ذَا}{حِجاباً وَلاَ طَرداً فَعَهدِى مُتَمَّمُ} \\
        \bayt{مَتَى ما أردَتَ القُربَ مِنّىِ فَنادِنِى}{أَلاَ يا رَسُولَ اللهِ إِنِّىَ مُغرَمُ} \\
        \bayt{أُجُيبُكَ مِن بُعدٍ وَإِنِّى جَلِيسُ مَن}{بِحُبِّىَ مَشغولٌ بِذِكرى مُتَرجِمُ} \\
        \bayt{حَلَفتُ يَمِيناً إِنَّ قَلباً يُحِبُّكُم}{عَلَيهِ عَذابُ النَّارِ قَطعاً مُحرَّمُ}\\
        \bayt{فَكَيفَ بمَن قَد شامَكُم كُلَّ ساعَةٍ}{فَهذَا يَقِيناً في الجِنانِ يُنَعَّمُ} \\
        \bayt{سَلاَمٌ عَلَيكُم وَالسَّلاَمُ يُنِيلُنِى}{كَمالَ شُهُودِ لِلجَمالِ وَيُلهِمُ} \\
        \bayt{لِسانِى تَحِيَّاتٍ تَلِيقُ بِقَدرِكُم}{ أُكُرِّرُها في حَيَّكُم وَأُهمهِم} \\
        \bayt{سَلاَمٌ علَى رَأسِ الرَّسُولِ مُحَمَّدٍ}{لَرَأسٌ جَلِيلٌ بالجَلاَلِ مُعَمَّمُ} \\ 
        \bayt{سَلاَمٌ علَى وَجهِ النَّبِىِّ مُحَمَّدٍ}{فَيا نِعمَ وَجهٌ بالضِّياءِ مُلَثَّمُ} \\
        \bayt{سَلاَمٌ عَلى طَرفِ النَّبِىِّ مُحَمَّدٍ}{لَطَرفٌ كَحِيلٌ أَدعجٌ وَمُعَلَّمُ} \\
        \bayt{سَلاَمٌ عَلى أنفِ النَّبِىِّ مُحَمَّدٍ}{لأَنفٌ عَدِيلٌ أنوَرٌ وَمُقَوَّمُ} \\
        \bayt{سَلامٌ علَى خَدّ الحَبيبِ مُحَمَّدٍ}{ لَخَدٌ مُنِيرٌ أسهَلٌ وَمُشَمَّمُ} \\
        \bayt{سَلاَمٌ علَى فَمِّ النَّبِىِّ مُحَمَّدٍ}{ لَفَمٌّ بِهِ دُرٌّ نَفِيسٌ مُنَظَّمُ} \\
        \bayt{بِغَيرِ كَلاَمِ اللهِ وَالذِّكرِ وَالنّدَا}{لِحَضرَةِ مَولاَهُ فَلاَ يَتَكَلمُ} \\
        \bayt{سَلامٌ علي عُنق النَّبِىِّ مُحَمَّدٍ}{لَعُنقٌ سَطِيعٌ نَيِّرٌ وَمُبَرَّمُ} \\ 
        \bayt{سَلاَمٌ على صَدرِ الحَبِيبِ مُحَمَّدٍ}{لَصَدرٌ وَسِيعٌ بالعُلُومِ مُطَمطَمُ} \\ 
        \bayt{سَلاَمٌ على قَلبِ الحَبيبِ مُحَمَّدٍ}{لَقلبٌ بِنُورِ اللهِ دَوماً مُقَيَّمُ} \\ 
        \bayt{يُشَاهِدُ رَبَّ العَرشِ في كُلِّ لَحظَةٍ}{ فإن نامَتِ العَينانِ ما نامَ فاعلَمُوا} \\
        \bayt{سَلاَمٌ على كَفِّ النبي مُحَمَّدٍ}{لَكَفٌ رَحيبٌ كَم يَجُودُ وَيُكرِمُ} \\
        \bayt{بهِ كَم فَقِيرٍ صَارَ مِن بَعدِ فَقرِهِ}{غَنِيًّا وَكَم طاغٍ بهِ مُتَضَيِّمُ}\\
        \bayt{سَلاَمٌ على قَدَمٍِ الحَبيبِ مُحَمَّدٍ}{بهِ دَاسَ حُجبَ العِزِّ ذَاكَ المُقَدِّمُ} \\
        \bayt{بهِ قامَ في المِحرَابِ لِلهِ قانِتاً}{يُناجى لِرَبِّ العَرشِ وَالنَّاسُ نُوَّمُ} \\
        \bayt{فَما زَالَ هذَا دَأبُهُ كُلَّ لَيلَةٍ}{ إِلى أَن بهِ بانَ الوَنا وَالتَّوَرُّمُ} \\
        \bayt{سَلاَمٌ على ذَاتِ النبي مُحَمَّدٍ}{فَيا حُسنَها فِيها الجَمالُ مُتَمَّمُ} \\
        \bayt{سَلاَمٌ عَلى كُلِّ النبي مُحَمَّدٍ}{ نبي عَظِيمٌ بالجَلالِ مُعَظَّمُ} \\
        \bayt{نَبِىٌ لِمَولاَهُ العَلِّى عِنايَةٌ}{بِهِ تَبدُو إِذ ما الخَلقُ في الحَشرِ يُفحَمُ} \\
        \bayt{عَلَيهِ لِوَاءُ الحَمدِ يُنصَبُ رِفعَةً}{وَمِن تَحتِهِ الانباءُ وَالرُّسلُ يُزحَمُ} \\
        \bayt{بِهِ كُلُّ عاص في القِيامةِ لاَئِذٌ}{وَكُلُّ مُحِبٍّ فائِزٌ وَمُكلَّمُ} \\
        \bayt{بِهِ يَرتَجِى المَجذُوبُ يَنجُو بِصَحبهِ }{بِغَيرِ امتِحانٍ يا شَفِيعُ وَيَسلَمُ} \\
        \bayt{عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه}{ يَعُمَّانِ كلَّ الآلِ ها نحن نختمُ} \\
        
        \end{arabverse}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: `bidipoem` is for use with `xelatex`, whereas `arabluatex` is for use with `lualatex`.

Comment: Thanks for the specifying which goes with which. Now, is there a way to make texnegar work with ArabLuaTeX?

Comment: With `arabluatex` stretching of lines should first be disabled with `\StretchBayt[false]` for this to work. Also I would advice to use `Scheherazade New` with Harfbuzz as renderer. This release of Scheherazade does not need to be scaled anymore. I will run some tests to see whether and how `texnegar` works wth `arabluatex`.

Comment: @RobertAlessi This might help: I get an option-clash for `xcolor` package. Removing that clash, kashida visibly activates when the line is short enough. Using font `HM XKayhan` from (https://bitbucket.org/dma8hm1334/persian-hm-xs2-3.8/downloads/), via (https://dma8hm1334.bitbucket.io/persian-hm-xs2/index-xs2.html).

Comment: @Cicada Do you mean "when the line is _long_ enough"?  Loading `texnegar` before `arabluatex` removes the clash: is this what you did on your side? That said, the kashida still doesn't show on my test file.

Comment: @RobertAlessi If I use Harfbuzz Renderer, the file does not compile. Otherwise, both Scheherazade and Scheherazade new work fine. In the example above, the multicols section shows the kashida very well. You can change font size or margins to see that clearly. But in the arabverse or traditionalpoem environments, it get disabled or doen't work.

Comment: @Cicada In my computer, Scheherazade font work just like HM XKayhan. I tried your advice by shortening some lines and changing the poem's margins, nothing worked. Kashida just doesn't show up.

Comment: @yacine Nothing wrong with Harfbuzz on my side.  As for the kashida in bidipoem and arabverse, I can see it where you typed it, unless it is not red. Right?

Comment: @RobertAlessi Yes. I have typed some kashidas just to see if they appear. The standard behavior should put kashidas wherever necessary and color it. I have noticed that by switching the color off, the compilation takes much less time (in a longer text) and the rendering of kashidas is fine with the HM XKayhan font, but not with Scheherazade or Scheherazade New, in multicols environment but not in poetry environments.

Comment: @yacine For compilation time, try `Kashida=leaders+glyph`, which doesn't write to the `.aux` file like `Kashida=glyph` does. Also, for display time, if you zoom in on the PDF, you can see which method uses many many small boxes to draw the rule and the PDF viewer has to process all those.

Comment: With `arabluatex` `leaders+glyph` does not work well: kashidas are rendered in white. `glyph` works, but I am under the impression that at least a natural line break is needed for the kashidas to be generated, which does not happen in lines of poetry.  It may be worth submitting the issue to the author of `texnegar`.

Comment: @Cicada and RobertAlessi I have created a Bitbucket linking it to this page. Hopefully we will get a comment from the author. https://bitbucket.org/dma8hm1334/texnegar/issues/1/texnegar-with-arabic-poems-in-lualatex

Comment: @RobertAlessi yes line length is a factor: I used a 1 inch wide minipage, otherwise stretching was minimal or zero (at a normal font size). Maybe `\textwidth` could be used for a poem. Anyway, wait and see. It's good that it works with transliteration (using `novoc` option, though).

Comment: @Cicada Both ṣadr and ʿaǧuz are typeset within horizontal boxes, where line breaks cannot occur.  But yes,`texnegar` seems to work otherwise with `arabluatex`!  @yacine Thanks for reporting this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is now fixed in the new version (0.1c) of [texnegar](https://ctan.org/pkg/texnegar) uploaded on CTAN today. Please find below the result of `kashida` implementation for `HM XKayhan`, `Adobe Arabic`, `Amiri`, `Scheherazade New` and `Scheherazade`. To test a new font just redefine the CS `\FontName` in the following code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\def\FontName{HM XKayhan}
% \def\FontName{Adobe Arabic}
% \def\FontName{Amiri}
% \def\FontName{Scheherazade New}
% \def\FontName{Scheherazade}

\newdimen\oldhsize
\oldhsize=\hsize

\def\SampleTitle#1#2{{\noindent\large \pardir TLT \textdir TLT Engine: {\color{blue}\texttt{LuaTeX using texnegar}}, \\
     Font: {\color{blue}\texttt{\FontName}}, \\ Style: {\color{blue}\texttt{Regular}}, \\
     Kashida: {\color{blue}\texttt{#2}}}\hbox{}\vskip 5mm}

\def\SampleTextOne{\pardir TRT \textdir TRT
   این یک  آزمایش است. \linebreak[4] }

\def\SampleTextTwo{\pardir TRT \textdir TRT
  راهی جایی تابی چاپی چاههی  
  شتابهایی تابی چاپی راهی تلاشهــایی 
  که کتابهایی که کلاههایی که کتابهایی }

\pretolerance = 10000

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[Minimal=On,Kashida=glyph,kashidastretch=0.14 em plus 0.5 em,hboxrecursion=On,vboxrecursion=On,color=red]{texnegar}
% \usepackage[Minimal=On,Kashida=leaders+glyph,kashidastretch=0.14 em plus 0.5 em,hboxrecursion=On,vboxrecursion=On,color=red]{texnegar}
% \usepackage[Minimal=On,Kashida=leaders+hrule,kashidastretch=0.14 em plus 0.5 em,hboxrecursion=On,vboxrecursion=On,color=red]{texnegar}

\setfontfamily\FontNl[Script=Arabic,Language=Persian,Scale=1.5]{\FontName}
\setfontfamily\FontRm[Script=Arabic,Language=Persian,Scale=4.5]{\FontName}

\begin{document}
  \KashidaOff \SampleTitle{\FontName}{Off} \par
  \vbox{\hsize=2in \KashidaOff \FontNl \SampleTextOne } \par
  \hsize=3in \KashidaOff { \FontNl \SampleTextOne } \par \vskip 20pt
  \hsize=\oldhsize { \FontRm \SampleTextTwo }
  \newpage
  \KashidaOn \SampleTitle{\FontName}{glyph (On)} \par
  \vbox{\hsize=2in \KashidaOn \FontNl \SampleTextOne } \par
  \hsize=3in \KashidaOn { \FontNl \SampleTextOne } \par \vskip 20pt
  \hsize=\oldhsize { \FontRm \SampleTextTwo }
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It works great! I didn't find any issues and the outcome is nice.

Comment: With `Amiri`  font  `\KashidaOn` do not work on my pc (updated texlive 2020) !! 
here log file https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IVJ4V

Comment: According to the log file, you are using version `0.1d` of `texnegar`. So, adding the option `Kashidafontfamily=Amiri` should fix the problem.

Comment: @dma8hm1334 this solve the issue, thanks for your interesting and useful package.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this issue is to redefine the command `\bayt` as follows:

```
\documentclass[A4paper,11pt]{book}
% \usepackage[Kashida=leaders+glyph,kashidastretch=0.14 em plus 0.5 em,hboxrecursion=On,vboxrecursion=On,color=red,ligatures=default]{texnegar}
\usepackage[Kashida=glyph,kashidastretch=0.14 em plus 0.5 em,hboxrecursion=On,vboxrecursion=On,color=red,ligatures=default]{texnegar}
\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
% \babelfont{rm}[Language=Default,Scale=2]{Scheherazade}
% \babelfont{sf}[Language=Default,Scale=2]{Scheherazade}
\babelfont{rm}[Language=Default,Scale=2]{HM XKayhan}
\babelfont{sf}[Language=Default,Scale=2]{HM XKayhan}
\babelfont[french]{rm}{Junicode}
\babeltags{ar = arabic}
\babeltags{fr = french}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bidipoem}
\usepackage{arabluatex}    
\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\bayt}{s m o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\relax}{\relax}%
  \ifdefined\savenotes\savenotes\else\fi%
  \edef\al@tatweel{--}%
  \ifal@warp@bayt%
    \adjustbox{width=\al@bayt@width, height=\Height}{\arb@utf{#2}}%
  \else%
    % \makebox[\al@bayt@width][s]{\arb@utf{#2}}%
    \makebox[\al@bayt@width][s]{\vbox{\hsize=\al@bayt@width \KashidaOn \arb@utf{#2} \linebreak[4]}}%
  \fi%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
    \ifal@verse@delim\makebox[\al@gutter@width][c]{\al@hemistich@delim}%
    \else%
    \hspace{\al@gutter@width}%
    \fi
  }{%
    \edef\@tempa{#3}%
    \ifx\@tempa\al@tatweel%
    \ifx\al@mode\al@mode@trans%
    \hspace{\al@gutter@width}%
    \else%
    \makebox[\al@gutter@width][s]{\al@verse@stroke}%
    \fi%
    \else%
    \ifx\al@mode\al@mode@trans%
    \ifal@warp@bayt%
      \adjustbox{width=\al@gutter@width, height=\Height}{\arb@utf{#3}}%
    \else%
      \makebox[\al@gutter@width][s]{\arb@utf{#3}}%
    \fi%
    \else%
    \makebox[\al@gutter@width][s]{\arb@utf{#3}}%
    \fi\fi}%
  \ifal@warp@bayt%
    \adjustbox{width=\al@bayt@width, height=\Height}{\arb@utf{#4}}%
  \else%
    % \makebox[\al@bayt@width][s]{\arb@utf{#4}}%
    \makebox[\al@bayt@width][s]{\vbox{\hsize=\al@bayt@width \KashidaOn \arb@utf{#4} \linebreak[4]}}%
  \fi%
  \ifdefined\spewnotes\spewnotes\else\fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%Source: https://blogs.harvard.edu/sulaymanibnqiddees/tag/arabic-sufi-poetry/
        
عــليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه   ألا يا رسول الله إنى مغرم عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه   ألا يـا رسول الله إنى مغرم عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه    ألا يا رسول الله إنى مغرم

وَلَيسَ لَهُ مِن ذَا التَّتَيُّمِ مُشرِحٌ    سِوَى أن يَرَى مَعشُوقَهُ فَيُسَلِّمُ
 علــيك صلاة الله ثم سلامه     ألا يــا رسول الله إنى مغرم
 صَبَبتُ دُمُوعاً يَشهَدُ الحُزنُ أَنَّه   أَتَت مِن فُؤَادٍ بالغَرَامِ مُتَيَّمُ

\begin{multicols}{3}
عــليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه   ألا يا رسول الله إنى مغرم عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه   ألا يـا رسول الله إنى مغرم عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه    ألا يا رسول الله إنى مغرم عــليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه   ألا يـا رسول الله إنى مغرم عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه   ألا يـا رسول الله إنى مغرم عليك صلاة الله ثم سلامه    ألا يا رسول الله إنى مغرم
\end{multicols}

\begin{arabverse}[width=.45\linewidth]
  \let\arabicfont\empty
  \StretchBayt[false]
  \bayt{ صببت دموعا }{ يشهد الحزن انها } \\
  \bayt{ أَتَت مِن فُؤَادٍ }{ بالغَرَامِ مُتَيَّمُ } \\
\end{arabverse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution. It worked like a charm for the HM XKayhan font, and the like. Is there a possibility to make it work with Scheherazade or Amiri fonts, for example?

Comment: It should work with any font that has the `kashida` glyph, but with the option `glyph`, or with `leaders+hrule` for all fonts. The option `leaders+glyph` can be used with the HM fonts only.

Comment: When I use the MWE you provide above, and change the option `glyph` to `leaders+glyph` and change the font to `Amiri`, all the kashidas are removed. If I change font to `Scheherazade`, only the kashidas that I specifically added by hand appear.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is a bug in texnegar, and I will try to fix it in the later versions. However, please note that the code works fine with Adobe Arabic font. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Thank you in advance! I appreciate the work you are doing. I am looking forward to the next version.